# Is possible to change variable type dinamically based on it's value type?

Tags: typescript

i would like to use a typescript variable allow to assume different type based on it's value, mantaining type check (so i need to avoid 'any').

For example:

```
class Car
{
    public string LicensePlate;
}
class Driver
{
    public string Name;
}

function GetCar(licensePlate: string): Car { ... }
function GetDriver(name: string): Driver { ... }

let licensePlate: string;
let name: string;

let result = GetCar("123");
licensePlate = result.LicensePlate;

result = GetDriver("Bob");
name = result.Name;
```

basically i need to "reuse" a variable with different type values, mantaining type check.

Can typescript allow this?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but I'd recommend not using the same variable to store multiple unrelated objects in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you initialize without any type, it can be converted
Simply declare variable without type, like `let test1`

```
class A {
  val1: string
}
class B {
  val2: number
}

// OK
let test1
test1 = new A()
console.log('test1', (test1 as A).val1) // requires type cast
test1 = new B()
console.log('test1', (test1 as B).val2) // requires type cast

// Error
let test2 = new A()
console.log('test2', test2.val1)        // dont need type cast
test2 = new B()                         // Property 'val1' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'
console.log('test2', test2.val2)        // Property 'val2' does not exist on type 'A'
console.log('test2', (test2 as B).val2) // Conversion of type 'A' to type 'B' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other
```

Comment: no, as far as you declare your variable of type any, it requires type cast

Comment: my goai is to get a "dynamic" type so i can use the variable for different result type but if i need to cast every time it's unconfortable. I have tested with typescript playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code) and declaring a variable without typing and then assign different types work well with intellisense and without need to cast... strange..

Comment: Probably it's new version of typescript, that implicitly infers types, good for you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Update Typescript version to 3.5.3
2. Set noImplicitAny flag

Now i can do:

```
let result; //Here result type is any   
result = new A(); //Here result type is A   
result = new B(); //Here result type is B
```

and intellisense and type check work like a charm based on variable assignment